# Using Date Logic in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, db2

I'm trying include date logic that follows this line of reasoning:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(ACLS_PROD, 'SELECT A182.BK_NUM as Bank,
A182.LN_NUM as Loan_Number,
A182.ACT_STA as Ln_Sta,
A182.NXT_PMT_DUE_DAT as Due_Date,
A182.CUR_LN_BAL as Balance,
A182.INS_REF_NUM as Debt_Can_Ref

FROM PZFRL.ALT0182 A182

WHERE A182.ACT_STA IN(''0'', ''1'', ''2'')
AND (A182.INS_REF_NUM IN(''SDC'', ''SDD'', ''SDU'', ''SLF'', ''SUF'', ''DSF'', 
''JDC'', ''JDD'', ''JDU'', ''JLF'', ''JDF'')
AND A182.NXT_PMT_DUE_DAT <= GETDATE())

ORDER BY A182.BK_NUM,
A182.LN_NUM

')
```

In SAS, you can use TODAY() to accomplish that.  Does SQL have an equivalent date function that I can implement? When I use CURDATE() and GETDATE(), I get the following error in the message log:

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ACLS_PROD" returned message "[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0206N "CURDATE" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703
".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 19
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ACLS_PROD".

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: The "S" in SQL doesn't stand for "standardized" -- it stands for "structured".  Very little is 100% consistent across different databases, so specify which you are using if you want to get useful help.

Comment: Are you interested in the answer for DB2?  You have that as a tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I added the DB2 tag, because the error message is for the DB2 OLE driver.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Oh, I see.  Does that mean the DBMS at the far end is DB2, in which case my answer is apposite, or is there a MS SQL Server at the far end?  I'm not clear which is the case (and maybe the OP isn't either).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I read the error as being DB2 is the remote host, which would explain using OPENQUERY, so the issue would appear to be DB2 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp), the 'special register' called `CURRENT DATE` (two words) give you the current date.

No parentheses; just `CURRENT DATE` in place `GETDATE()`.

Comment: [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005870.html) should work as well.

Comment: @galador: Standard SQL says `CURRENT DATE`; when I searched for 'current_date' at the DB2 10.1 Info Center (link in answer), then I got back: _The CURRENT DATE (or CURRENT_DATE) special register specifies a date that is based on a reading of the time-of-day clock when the SQL statement is executed at the application server._  So, you're correct, a single word with underscore works too, and is SQL standard compliant.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but the link you posted just goes to the main page of the Info Center (because IBM uses frames).  To link to the actual page, you can find a link at the very bottom of each article (like in my link).

Comment: @galador: Thanks for the up-vote. I intended to provide a link to the DB2 Info Center.  If I'd intended to provide a link direct to CURRENT DATE, the link would have been around CURRENT DATE and not (or, as well as) around DB2.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I AM NOT a DB2 developer; I've never run so much as one query on it before.

That having been said, from the error message you copied, it looks like it's trying to run against a DB2 database.  As such, can you just use `current time` instead of GETDATE()?  Here's what I found in about 15 seconds of Googling [DB2 current date](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html).

Hope that helps, and good luck.